# Can a Mac's airport card run 802.11 N, G, B or A only?

Tags: wifi, macos

Occasionally it's nice to hard code a wired connection network port to not auto negotiate and force things to be 100 half duplex even though a higher speed is configured and negotiable on the switch.

Can I similarly force airport software and thus the hardware to only run one flavor of 802.11? Can I use the `airport` command to prefer a higher / lower channel rather than join by signal strength? Might alternative drivers be available or some developer testing tool to exert this level of control over the WiFi chipsets in Macs.

I want to force this on the mac end for cases where I can't control the base stations or want to test a specific channel of a simultaneous dual band router that is live with other traffic.

```
mac:bin mike$ airport --scan
                            SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                     na ala hele 00:26:36:9c:32:23 -59  2       Y  US WPA(PSK/TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
                     na ala hele 00:26:bb:79:23:1f -59  2       Y  US WPA(PSK/TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
                fast na ala hele 00:26:bb:79:23:20 -74  149,+1  Y  US WPA(PSK/TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
mac:bin mike$ airport --getinfo
     agrCtlRSSI: -75
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -86
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 81
        maxRate: 300
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: 00:26:bb:79:23:20
           SSID: fast na ala hele
            MCS: 4
        channel: 149,1
mac:bin mike$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/airport 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  89 Sep 13 11:40 /usr/local/bin/airport -> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this help, you can access to the airport command utility with

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

Then, type

```
sudo airport en1 prefs JoinMode=Strongest JoinModeFallback=KeepLooking
```

JoinMode = Ranked and JoinModeFallback = Prompt are the defaults, if you want to switch back

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind - I wasn't aware of this tidbit and perhaps can exploit it in an indirect manner by getting as close to the network I prefer. It clearly won't work for dual band routers... I can't always depend on the channel I want to force my hardware being the strongest signal, but you've got me one step closer to a good solution.

Comment: I'm choosing this for the bounty as I've already got `/System/Library/CoreServices/Wi-Fi Diagnostics` for the pretty graphs and frame debugging. The airport command is the tool that would be able to set the radio - but it's documentation is lacking and it appears to be in transition to a new format. Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: What exactly is **JoinMode=Ranked**? It is documented anywhere quasi-offically?

Comment: why sudo? Network joining should be available for the regular user, right?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to check whether the base station is sending on the right channel, [Kismac](http://kismac-ng.org/) may be of use to you. This will show all modes that your Airport card supports, including dual-band base stations. It's also great for checking wi-fi coverage with the built-in signal monitor, which can chart signal strength as you walk around with laptop in hand.

[image: Overview]

[image: Signal chart]

Comment: Very nice link - I'll keep that in mind if I need more details. `airport --getinfo` and `airport --scan` currently work for my needs. Does Kismac do more than just interpreting the airport scan data that I can see from the command line?

Comment: Yes, much more, including some common WEP attacks. There's a [feature list](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/).

Comment: Wow - this is really a great tool. It's not what I need now - but I'll certainly give it a try in the future.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I think this is only possible at the router level. So that router's will only accept "X" traffic, and not at the broadcast level (your NIC). I suppose you could use ipfw to throttle bandwidth on certain machines, to do, um, your testing ;)

Comment: I am really looking to get at the radio on the mac. This would allow me to ignore all the b/g clutter if I want to see the one or two 802.11a routers. Also, for interference testing, I want to _know_ I'm measuring the n band and not have my mac hop to a lower channel - I need it to fail when it's pinned to one channel for the testing to be accurate.

Comment: Also the [Network Link Conditioner](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac) is great alternative to `ipfw` for light <strike>pranking</strike> _testing_.

Comment: Might you have any insight into this other question, cksum? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38125/airport-looking-for-networks-affects-firewire-audio-device - that OP is looking to hack at the guts of airport cards too

Answer (score 0):

With the Wireless Diagnostic that Apple introduced in 10.8.4 - I now have the beginnings of a workable answer.

Running the tool (which is in /System/Library/Core Services) by option clicking the Airport icon in the menu bar - I can capture arbitrary frames on any allowable channel (but not actually join a base station on this specified channel or radio mode). This saves a standard `tcpdump` file that can be analyzed. The Info tab in the **Utilities** window and the associated tools for Logging, Frame Capture, Wi-Fi Scan and Performance allow me to troubleshoot most wireless situations.

I have also added an Aerohive AP121 router to my toolset and that allows near real time FFT graphical spectrum analysis of tricky radio situations, but that's a bit of overkill for wanting an OS X tool to begin to tease apart challenging wireless environments.

No answer seems to let me control the OS X / radio software stack to force a connection or operation on one of the frequency bands, though so the answer seems to be no at the moment (as well as for quite some time).

Comment: bmike I'm also looking to do the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?