# How to choke network preformance on OS X

Tags: macos, network, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate slow internet connections on the mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac)

For testing purposes I would like to choke the performance of the network on my OS X 10.8.2 machine. 
I have currently Little Snitch installed, which I can block access to certain hosts with... however I would like to lower the network performance as if I would be using an 56k6 old-school modem.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Great wording - I'll point this to the canonical question we have on this tool and this will help guide everyone to the answers we have on Network Link conditioner.

Comment: Thnx! Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can use command-line tools to do this, Apple has a developer tool that allows you to do what you are talking about from a control panel. There are presets available, or you can set your own performance limits. The tool is called "Network Link Conditioner" and is available on Apple's developer download site with a package called "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode".

Here is a blog post discussing the tool (with screen shots):
http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/

Comment: I just found about that. Thanks. The link, however, is https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#

Comment: +1 for the link to the article - feel free to add that to the existing answers on the main thread for this. It's a very good article.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching and talking with a friend of mine, I found the `Hardware I/O tools for XCode` which has the `Network Link Conditioner` which does this kind of things.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#