# How to throttle usage of individual computer with Apple Airport?

Tags: airport

There are a bunch of kids in our house using wifi. When one is watching HD video on Youtube, everyone else can hardly load a webpage.

How can I customize the Apple Airport to throttle usage for all machines using the wifi?

Comment: The Airport Utility doesn't support connection throttling, so you may be out of luck here.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's hardware doesn't perform Quality of Service  - so you'd want to install a router that has QOS between the AirPort and the internet connection.

- http://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/

If all the children are on Mac or iOS - you could install a network link conditioner, but that is generally harder to administer and less effective at letting faster access when there isn't contention on the connection out of the house.

- [How to simulate slow internet connections on the mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac)

Before you select a new router, you'll want to determine what the total network speed is for the house. Optimizing for 10 users on 6/1 ADSL service is going to be harder than 4 users of 100 MB or fiber. The tools are the same, but the decisions you make and the end results will vary.