# Bandwidth limit downloads in Safari

Tags: macos, network, safari, high-sierra, internet

My browser is Safari.

If I want to download something, is there a way I can limit the download speed?

Doesn't necessarily have to use the Safari downloader (although that would be ideal), I assume I could copy/paste links into third party apps that may do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate slow internet connections on the mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac)

Comment: @Josh want it only for one application