# How to open console on ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, web-browser

Some of my users are sending me bug reports saying my website doesn't work on their device. They send me screenshots and videos of the problem. When I use all the simulators and the devices that I have they all seem to work fine.

So I'll need my user to send me the console log on their device so I can identify the problem.

I've searched online a lot and most of the answers are old and outdated. I guess not a lot of people build for mobile browser anymore. I found a way to use safari and connect to a mac but my user doesn't own any other device. So ipad is the only thing we can use.

Any solutions?

Comment: The answer you discarded is the answer, so I’ll post it. If I’m wrong, we will both learn something new :)

Answer (score 3):

Safari calls this the Web Inspector, so you’ll want to make your support clear by using the terms people will see. These developer tools are awesome for precisely what you seek.

Go to the settings app, Safari, Advanced.

[image]

As you can see this is a tethered operation where the data is shown on the desktop Safari. Most developers need to outsource this way and testing if you don’t find a Mac and iPad for testing and QA, but it’s entirely possible your users will help you to this level. It’s hard to be the developer and the tester since you know how you intended to use the app and can’t conceive of breaking it like someone who doesn’t know it uses the page in my experience. Also, timing delays and sketchy networks are hard to simulate in practice even when you [enable the Network Link Conditioner on your simulator and devices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac) for testing.

Comment: This answer suggests that the user needs to connect the ipad to a computer. But my user doesn't have a computer. Maybe I didn't make it clear in my question. All we can use is a mac.

Comment: No Mac, no console. Maybe I should have said - you lack what is needed more bluntly - I figured you would pick that up when I mentioned third party testers. You can’t test as the first party and your customers, second party, can’t test. You need more tools to do what you ask. @demiculus. I understood fully your people lack a Mac to test. It doesn’t change the situation, though.