# Can I slow down my iPhones network connection while testing an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, performance, development

I'm trying to test an iPhone app that needs to be usable in low-bandwidth / poor signal areas. I know [I can slow the network on my Mac and the simulator in Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24066/5472), but not how to slow iOS and iPadOS devices.

Can I slow the network connection on the physical devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Network Link Conditioner** should do what you want.
It's part of "Additional Tools for Xcode" and can be downloaded here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Additional%20Tools

Attach your iPhone to your Mac, launch Xcode and go to...

```
Window > Devices & Simulators
```

Select your iPhone in the sidebar (unlocked and displayed without errors)

On the iPhone you should now have the Developer settings:

```
Settings > Developer > Networking > Network Link Conditioner
```

See also: https://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/#enabling-network-link-conditioner-on-ios-devices

Comment: Works great. And I only needed to connect photo to Xcode once to activate the phone's Developer Tools --> Network Link Conditioner. So I can be out in the field testing unconnected to a laptop. Thanks!